# Excel formula: get ids ordered by distance

Tags: excel, sorting, excel-2010, vlookup

I have the following data:

```
ID          Distance
F11-001-A   22,56
F11-001-B   22,56
F11-002-A   22,56
V01-008-L   33,5
V01-009-Y   33,5
J01-008-L   80,3
J01-009-Y   80,3
M01-008-L   15,2
M01-009-Y   15,2
N01-008-L   8,7
N01-009-Y   8,7
Z01-099-I   55,5
A01-377-K   200,93
```

And I want to sort that data using an excel formula, by distance. The output should be:

```
Position    ID          Distance
1           N01-008-L   8,7
2           N01-009-Y   8,7
3           M01-008-L   15,2
4           M01-009-Y   15,2
5           F11-001-A   22,56
6           F11-001-B   22,56
7           F11-002-A   22,56
8           V01-008-L   33,5
9           V01-009-Y   33,5
10          Z01-099-I   55,5
11          J01-008-L   80,3
12          J01-009-Y   80,3
13          A01-377-K   200,93
```

The nearest thing I managed to do was using the following formula:

```
=SMALL(Data!$B$2:$B$14,A13)
```

But i want to first match the id's and only after match the distances using VLOOCKUP. That way shold be more "error proof". Could someone help me?
I will implement this in an excel file with thousands of lines of data.

Here is the excel file attached (with the sample data used in the example): https://transfer.sapo.pt/downloads/1fcb9b05-48db-4288-86c1-f94206a330fc/sapotransfer-5749504e95cbdhQ/

Any help is welcome. Thank you.

Comment: Why must you use a formula, is there a reason `Data -> Sort` doesn't work for you?

Comment: In my "real world" usage of this, I will calculate the distance dynamically (that is already implemented), and I want to keep data untouched.

Comment: You are sorting on two columns so not sure how formula (without helpers) would achieve this but I look forward to seeing if it can be done.

Comment: With the formula `SMALL(` i can get the data sorted in the way i want, but i want to get first the ID instead of the Distance (and then find the distance using VLOOKUP).

Comment: the file share link is unavailable..